# MySQL too slow it's take 1 hour 48 min to get 30 records from joining query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE `labels` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `print_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `template_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `series` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirm` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `views` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_by` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_at` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `labels`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `id` (`id`,`user_id`,`template_id`,`type`,`series`,
  `confirm`,`status`,`created_at`,`modified_at`),
  ADD KEY `id_2` 
 (`id`,`user_id`,`template_id`,`series`,`status`,`created_at`),
  ADD KEY `id_3` (`id`,`user_id`,`print_id`,`template_id`,`type`,`series`,
 `confirm`,`views`,`status`,`created_by`,`created_at`,`modified_at`),
  ADD KEY `id_4` 
 (`id`,`user_id`,`print_id`,`template_id`,`type`,
 `series`,`confirm`,`views`,`status`,`created_by`,
 `created_at`,`modified_at`);
ALTER TABLE `labels`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
CREATE TABLE `label_relations` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `label_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `related_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ALTER TABLE `label_relations`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `listIndex` (`id`,`label_id`,`type`,`related_id`);
ALTER TABLE `label_relations`
  MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

labels have 1337000 records
label_relations have 227000 records
label_logs have 215000 records

And i was run this query to get the relation with condition .

```
 SELECT `label_logs`.`id` FROM `label_logs`   
 LEFT JOIN `label_relations` AS `Relation` ON (`label_logs`.`label_id` = 
 `Relation`.`label_id`) WHERE `label_logs`.`status` = 1 
 AND `Relation`.`type` = 1  ORDER BY `label_logs`.`created_at` DESC  LIMIT 30;
```

But it's take a "30 rows in set (1 hour 48 min 48.18 sec)"

only with label_relations table ... when i query join with label_logs is normal

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to find out where you need an index.Also the whole join result will be ordered before you can get the 30 records

Comment: you  are  referring to table_logs in your query but i can't see  this table schema

Comment: As Jens already said all rows are ordered. Could you try order over an index? (if the order of id and created_at is the same, you can use the id instead ... `ORDER BY label_logs.id DESC`) .

Answer (score 1):

change your `label_relations`  index this way

```
 ADD KEY `listIndex` (`label_id`,`type`,`related_id`);
```

in your code the id before label_id can invalidate  the use of this index

and could be you need  the same for the `label_logs` table

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `label_log` records with status 1 where also exist a `label_relation` for the same label. Maybe you should write it thus.

```
SELECT id 
FROM label_logs
WHERE status = 1 
AND label_id IN (SELECT label_id FROM label_relations WHERE type = 1)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

For the query to run fast, I'd try these indexes:

```
create index idx1 on label_logs(status, label_id, created_at, id);
create index idx2 on label_logs(label_id, status, created_at, id);
create index idx3 on label_relations(label_id, type);
create index idx4 on label_relations(type, label_id);
```

Then use `EXPLAIN` to see which indexes are used and which not.

You can also replace the `IN` clause above with an `EXISTS` clause. MySQL used to have performance issues with `IN`. Hopefully it doesn't anymore, but who knows?

```
AND EXISTS
 (SELECT * FROM label_relations lr WHERE lr.type = 1 AND lr.label_id = label_logs.label_id)
```